# Memoir: Stopping hyphenation in chapter titles in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, hyphenation

I am working on my dissertation using xelatex and the `memoir` class. Many of the titles to my chapters contain long words which I don't want to be hypenated in the table of contents.

According the memoir class user guide, I should be able to use this command to achieve this:
`\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}`
This used to work, but now with more updated versions of tex it no longer works.

I always had this command in the preamble, but now it throws an error (`Missing \begin{document}`). Moving it to after `\begin{document}` does not solve this.

I realise that I *could* just manually add newlines to the chapter titles, but as I generate the titles with a command, this is not really useful.

I really just want to get the `@tocrmarg` command redefinition working ...

Who can help? I have attached a minimal example below (with the `\renewcommand` commented out):

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\newcommand{\lw}{Thisisalongwordverylong}

\chapter{\lw\ \lw\ \lw}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to deal with the `@`-sign in the command name. TeX does not recognize it as a part of the name. To solve it, enclose the whole `\renewcommand` to `\makeatletter...\makeatother`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{memoir}
\makeatletter %% HERE
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\makeatother %% AND HERE
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\newcommand{\lw}{Thisisalongwordverylong}

\chapter{\lw\ \lw\ \lw}

\end{document}
```